# Get good approximated segmentation mask within the detection rectangle

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, feature-detection, background-subtraction

I want to get a fast and good approximated segmentation of my object within its detection box. How could I do that? I tried background subtraction algorithms and grab cut but they dont look that promising.

Comment: Are you using a single web cam? What do you exactly want? What is your setup? Can you make any assumptions regarding the scene? Please be a little bit more specific.

Comment: Its an indoor application of a person walking in a room. Im using Kinect Sensor; It is mounted around 2m from the ground. Im using deformable part models for detecting the person. Thus I have the main detection box plus the smaller detection parts which where used to get the main detection box. I also have the detection score;

Comment: @Kostas can you post an example image + detection result + what you are expecting to get? why were you not satisfied with GrabCut? do you have an additional depth information?

Comment: have you considered [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27938800/1714410)?